# lumen 5.6 version not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have installed fresh copy of lumen 5.6 on my ubuntu machine. I also upgrade my php version from php 5.6.* to 7.2.5. Now php 7.2.5 version is enabled on my system. But when I run the project I receive frollowing exceptoion

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'
/home/example/apis/lumen/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php
```

Below is my php version

```
PHP 7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:59:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Guide to solve this problem or suggest any usefull link

Comment: u need to remove the older version.

Comment: @arun you mean I remove all my older php version and reinstall php 7.2?

Comment: no need to reinstall 7.2, just remove what u have installed previously. `sudo apt-get purge php5.6-common`

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `info.php` file inside your lumen public/ folder and open it on your server

```
<?php // info.php filename
phpinfo();
```

there is a good chance it is still referencing php 5.6?

You do not mention if you are serving the project via `php -S`, `apache` or `nginx`.

I am going to presume you are using `apache` as it mostly the default on Ubuntu. Disable the php 5.6 module for apache and enable the php 7.2 module. Something like the following will work.

- Disable php 5

`sudo a2dismod php5`

- Enable php 7.2

`sudo a2enmod php7.2`

- Restart apache

`sudo service apache2 restart`